# How to run the Android NDK install on Windows?

Tags: android, unix, android-ndk

Below are the only instructions I managed to find from Google on how to install the Android NDK, it is written as if we all run Linux and presumes we all understand what these obscure tools are. My comments and questions appear in italics if someone who knows Unix and Windows would translate, that would be great!

---

Android NDK Installation

Introduction:

Please read docs/OVERVIEW.TXT to understand what the Android NDK is and is not. This file gives instructions on how to properly setup your NDK.

I. Requirements:

The Android NDK currently requires a Linux, OS X or Windows host operating system. Windows users will need to install Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com) to use it. Note that running the NDK under MSys is not supported.

You will need to have the Android SDK and its dependencies installed. The NDK
cannot generate final application packages (.apk files), only the shared library files that can go into them.

IMPORTANT:

The Android NDK can only be used to target system images using the Cupcake (1.5) or later releases of the platform. This is due to subtle toolchain and ABI related changed that make it incompatible with 1.0 and 1.1 system images.

The NDK requires GNU Make 3.81 or later being available on your development system. Earlier versions of GNU Make might work but have not been tested.

You can check this by running 'make -v' from the command-line. The output should look like:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

On certain systems, GNU Make might be available through a different command like 'gmake' or 'gnumake'. For these systems, replace 'make' by the appropriate command when invoking the NDK build system as described in the documentation.

***Great, some strange thing called gnu make. If you're not going to tell me what it does maybe you then at least you could give me a URL to it?***

The NDK also requires a Nawk or GNU Awk executable being available on your
development system. Note that the original 'awk' program doesn't implement
the 'match' and 'substr' functions used by the NDK build system.

***OK, another tool, with 1 of 2 possible names, but not the third... and again where should I download this?***

On Windows, you will need to install a recent release of Cygwin to use the NDK. See http://www.cygwin.com for instructions.

***Woohoo a URL! Download took about a day because these install instructions do not specify what parts to download.***

II. Preparing your installation prebuilt cross-toolchain binaries:

After installing and unarchiving the NDK, you will need to run the following
command from the root folder:

build/host-setup.sh

***hello? Windows doesn't run anything but .exe .com or .dll, just tell me how you want me to run it.***

This will test your setup and make sure the NDK can work properly.

***Nothing is said about where any of these things need to be installed to (what directory)***

Comment: Welcome to the life of a swdev. Don't get frustrated.

Comment: Nathan, don't fret all the tools you asked questions about are tools you will see again and again om your Software Development Career. So just getting andrioid-ndk up and running you will be introduced to some important tools.

Comment: Actually even with all the great input here i think i am going to have to abondon my dreams of using the android NDK.. there are still to many variables that are not defined.. there is 100 different variations of what everything might mean.. but only 1 truth. I dont feel like spending 48 hours figuring it out.. when google knows what i need to know they just did not tell me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would highly recommend *not* developing this on windows. Go get [virtual box](http://www.sun.com/software/products/virtualbox/) and create an [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/) image (or whatever other flavor of linux you may prefer) and use that for development. I've been developing in the windows world with cygwin for several months now and I completely hate it. While cygwin is awesome, it's a complete hack onto windows and its only a matter of time before you discover that painful fact. You *will* run into issues with paths/executables/etc trying to get anything done within cygwin. Configuration nightmares abound when it comes to specifying where things are in cygwin versus windows. The whole thing really just sucks. If the development environment requires cygwin, I would highly suggest just going with linux instead. You will love yourself later on for it - I wish I would have done it months ago.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunitly i spend 1/2 of my dev time on campus, and they just dont have any linux boxs setup.. so whatever i do i need to try and make it fit on my thumb drive and not require much to be installed otherwise..

Comment: You could easily get virtual box and a linux image onto a flash drive (maybe 2-4 gigs), and take it with you anywhere you go. Have your own development environment in a bottle! All you'd have to do would be to install virtual box. It'd take all of 10 minutes tops at any computer you sat down at. And would be well worth that 10 minutes to have your own personalized development environment anywhere you went.

Comment: And what the hell kind of college doesn't have any linux boxes? ;)

Comment: Affordable ones, (community college), with a nazi tech department. lol.. why cant i just write inline C, and ecplipse IDE figures all the useless compiling crud out. ohwell.

Comment: if it where actually easyer.. i mean its hard enough trying to figure out what all of this means... throw in a operating system swich to something as alien as linux..it would probibly be a month before i wrote a single line of code. im sure linux is great and all but if it takes to long to figure out, and the result is only being able to do what i should of been able to do in windows if google had just given correct instructions/installer... i mean heck after a month of leaning linux google may have released a NDK installer before i wrote 1 line of code.

Comment: The thing is... Android phones run Linux, so you have to know it anyway.  There is no alternative, you have to understand your target environment.

Comment: Well that nazi tech department needs to follow my suggestions and get linux running on some of those machines. It's completely free, and you can't do any damage whatsoever to the underlying operating system with a virtualized OS running on top. It's pointless not to have a lab that has linux on it. That college is doing a major disservice to anyone studying computer science - a large portion of development positions use either mac or linux. It's rare I come across a developer position using windows. Just my personal experience - I'm sure people will hollar otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

> Great some strange thing called gnu make.. if your not going to tell me what it does maybe you then at least you could give me a URL to it?

This is a fundamental part of the Unix build system, and you're going to have to learn it.  They're assuming you're fairly familiar with Linux development.

> windows dont run nothing but .exe .com or .dll, just tell me how you want me to run it..

That's what you downloaded Cygwin for.  Do that from a Cygwin bash prompt.  AWK probably came with Cygwin.

> Nothing is said about where any of these things need to be installed to (what directory)

Because they're running from the root folder of the SDK install, it isn't going to matter.  The host-setup.sh script might record where it is for later reference, so do run that from where you intend to keep it.

Answer (score 6):

You're expected to run everything from within Cygwin, which is a linux-like environment for Windows.  The instructions clearly expect you to understand how to use Cygwin, which is a subject too broad for them to include in their instructions.  All the "obscure" tools it references can be installed using the Cygwin setup/installer program (the same one that installed Cygwin on your computer).

Comment: does cygwin install make or gmake or gnumake or whatever make as well? i am pretty sure i told it to download everything and i cant find anything besides makeinfo...

Comment: @nathan: "make" is probably available under the "development" section of Cygwin's package manager.  It is probably installed by default, but I can't remember for sure.  If you told it to install everything, then you must have it :)  But I didn't even realize there was a way to do that... it must take forever.  Go back into the package managar (setup/installer program) and double check.

Comment: as far as i can tell its installed, but where would it be in the c:\cygwin\ folder structure?

Comment: Make is always /usr/bin/make, so translate that into cygwin-speak.

Comment: Type `which make` to see where exactly a command is being executed from. `which` just shows you where the first one on your path is hiding.

Comment: Which of course when using cygwin prompt, it will show it being in an entirely different place (`/usr/bin/make`) than where it actually resides on your system (`C:\<path_to_where_cygwin_is_installed>/bin/make`). It's crap like this that makes me highly recommend just going with linux instead of cygwin. Granted, this is a harmless example, but I guarantee you will encounter this when it is -not- harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding running an .sh file, you'll do that in Cygwin.

Comment: what .exe file opens this bash prompt thing?